# How to install an app through Winebottler using a .exe file on Mac

Tags: macos, wine

Disclaimer: Question related to debugging code, not exactly sure if allowed on Stack Overflow but disregard if so

I've been trying to install an app. I downloaded the windows version of the app online and obtained a .exe file. Through various  guides I was obstructed to use Winebottler and select the .exe file , as well as a selection of 'Winetricks' and then install the program.[this is an image of what I tried on Winebottler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31iby.png)

However, when I try to install, a "Prefix creation exited with error" occurs and a logfile to debug is sent to my desktop. I'm not entirely capable of debugging this however, and was wondering if anyone could help or point me in the write direction. Here is the code:

```
      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro14,1
      Processor Name: Dual-Core Intel Core i5
      Processor Speed: 2.3 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 2
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 4 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 8 GB
      Boot ROM Version: 202.0.0.0.0
      SMC Version (system): 2.43f7
      Serial Number (system): FVFWQ2JLHV29
      Hardware UUID: AEEB4D21-3894-5AE9-973C-DEFCDD044F9F

###BOTTLING### Create .app...
###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat menus...
/Applications/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: 
line 142: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
### LOG ### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/
reg.reg' returned status 126.



###ERROR### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/
reg.reg' returned status 126.
Task returned with status 1.
```

I know there is a question very similar to this on Stack Overflow, but it's been up for a while and hasn't been answered so I asked again. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help.

Answer (score 5):

Just been trying to get this working myself (quite new to macOS). Running macOS Catalina ... I think the key is "Bad CPU type in executable", as I found the following in another forum;

"macOS Catalina has dropped all support for running 32 bit applications, so 32 bit Wine currently doesn't run on macOS Catalina, unfortunately."

Even the expensive "CodeWeavers Project" is having trouble with this.

Comment: But then read this on the author web site... https://mike.kronenberg.org/category/winebottler/ ... and realise that 64bit is suppoted in the latest release of WineBottler. Just use "Advanced" to install your own. I guess a lot of the convenient installers provided are still 32bit?

Comment: I am still having troubles with this today