# WineBottler: Prefix creation exited with error

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, wine

I'm trying to install a windows program through winebottler. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this? I tried messing around with the system version, but it's really no use it seems. If there's any other program that could handle it that would be great too. I tried to install through both the developer and the stable version of winebottler.

```
###BOTTLING### default.sh
/var/folders/kh/2mwf9_0513j860jvn_0nvs8w0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/C1851059-0277-467F-9E04-CE3EB0664F8C/d/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 39: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
###BOTTLING### Gathering debug Info...

Versions
OS...........................: darwin19
Wine.........................: 
WineBottler..................: 4.0.1.1
Wineticks....................: 20200412-next - sha256sum: 04f9048f4d273175ef008c326c248756be40695671c28a2f10e05a5c78a544ee

Environment
PWD..........................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
PATH.........................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
USER.........................: tigeroic
HOME.........................: /Users/tigeroic
COMPUTERNAME.................: MacBook Pro
BUNDLERESOURCEPATH...........: /var/folders/kh/2mwf9_0513j860jvn_0nvs8w0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/C1851059-0277-467F-9E04-CE3EB0664F8C/d/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources
WINEARCH.....................: win32
WINEPREFIX...................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources
WINEPATH.....................: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH..............: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH...: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/lib:/usr/lib
SILENT.......................: 
http_proxy...................: 
https_proxy..................: 
ftp_proxy....................: 
socks5_proxy.................: 

Bottle
TEMPLATE.....................: 
BOTTLE.......................: /Users/tigeroic/Downloads/Untitled.app
INSTALLER_URL................: /Users/tigeroic/Downloads/Streamlabs+Chatbot+Installer (1).exe
INSTALLER_IS_ZIPPED..........: 0
INSTALLER_NAME...............: Streamlabs+Chatbot+Installer (1).exe
INSTALLER_ARGUMENTS..........: 
REMOVE_MONO..................: 
REMOVE_GECKO.................: 
REMOVE_USERS.................: 
REMOVE_INSTALLERS............: 
WINETRICKS_ITEMS.............: arch=32 win7 
DLL_OVERRIDES................: 
EXECUTABLE_PATH..............: winefile
EXECUTABLE_ARGUMENTS.........: 
EXECUTABLE_VERSION...........: 1.0.0
BUNDLE_COPYRIGHT.............: Â© Your Company
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER............: com.yourcompany.yourapp
BUNDLE_CATEGORYTYPE..........: public.app-category.business
BUNDLE_SIGNATURE.............: 
SILENT.......................: 

Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: MacBook Pro
      Model Identifier: MacBookPro16,1
      Processor Name: 8-Core Intel Core i9
      Processor Speed: 2,3 GHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 8
      L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
      L3 Cache: 16 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Enabled
      Memory: 32 GB
      Boot ROM Version: 1037.120.87.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.15300.0.0,0)
      Serial Number (system): C02CQ8LHMD6T
      Hardware UUID: 25B3D8F4-FE4D-542F-8298-DF4919802B9B
      Activation Lock Status: Enabled

###BOTTLING### Create .app...
###BOTTLING### Enabling CoreAudio, Colors, Antialiasing  and flat menus...
/var/folders/kh/2mwf9_0513j860jvn_0nvs8w0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/C1851059-0277-467F-9E04-CE3EB0664F8C/d/WineBottler.app/Contents/Frameworks/WBottler.framework/Resources/bottler.sh: line 142: /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine: Bad CPU type in executable
### LOG ### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.



###ERROR### Command '/Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine regedit /tmp/reg.reg' returned status 126.
Task returned with status 1.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install an app through Winebottler using a .exe file on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296894/how-to-install-an-app-through-winebottler-using-a-exe-file-on-mac)